# Values of Java fields are not shown in aem component

Tags: java, aem, sling, sightly

I have aem component and Sling model with three injected fields corresponding to dialog fields in component. Only value of `headline` field is shown on the component. I tried to change the type of other fields to textfield, but that didn't make any effect. I don't see any other difference among my fields.

Here is Java class:

```
@Model(
    adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class},
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
public class ArticlePreviewImpl implements ArticlePreview {
  @Inject
  private String contentpath;
  
  @Inject
  private String headline;
  
  @Inject
  private String elements;
  
  @Override
  public String getContentpath() {
    return contentpath;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String getHeadline() {
    return headline;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String getElements() {
    return elements;
  }
}
```

Here is HTL:

```
<!--/* articlepreview.html */-->
<div class="cmp-apreview"
     data-sly-use.apreview="com.training.core.models.ArticlePreview">
        path: ${apreview.contentPath}<br/>
        headline: ${apreview.headline}<br/>
        elements: ${apreview.elements}
</div>
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"></sly>
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='cq.authoring.dialog, training.components'}"></sly>
```

Here are definitions of dialog fields from .content.xml:

```
<contentPath
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathfield"
fieldLabel="Path to directory with content"
name="./contentpath"/>
...
<headline
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
emptyText="Enter the headline to display."
fieldLabel="Headline"
name="./headline"/>
...
<elements
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield"
defaultValue="3"
fieldDescription="Number of elements in one portion"
fieldLabel="Number of elements in one portion"
max="{Double}15.0"
min="{Double}1.0"
name="./elements"
value="3"/>
```

Only value of `apreview.headline` is shown on the component, the two others are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very easy and stupid - I pushed HTL into repository instead of building entire project

Answer (score 0):

For `${apreview.contentPath}` you need to change your getter to `getContentPath` (note the camel**C**ase). For `${apreview.elements}` the getter looks ok, you'll need to check if the property is populated correctly in JCR for your resource (as the `DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL` allows null fields during injection).

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed `contentPath`, but nothing changed. I've checked `elements` property, but it changes correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to update your sling model property type to `Double` instead of `String`? Another thing would be to use a different name for the property, just in case `elements` is reserved by some custom type or mixin.

Comment: In JCR this property is String. I tried to rename it to visibleEntries, no effect.